# Endless scroll doesn't work in AngularJS when scrolling over a ng-view

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am using code like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/vojtajina/U7Bz9/) to create an endless scroll effect in AngularJS. I tried to refactor some of the code, by moving the content of the scrollable container (in this case the `ul`) to a seperate html file, and then use a ng-view to load the content.

After this is done the `scope.$apply(attr.whenScrolled);` doesn't have any effect. The `loadMore()` method is simply not called anymore.

Have I changed something about the scope after moving the ul-content to a seperate file, and loading it in dynamically?

Update:
Here is the code:

```
App.directive('whenScrolled', function() {
return function(scope, element, attr) {
    var raw = element[0];

    // binding on element doesn't work so this is a temp fix
    $(document).bind('scroll', function() {
      var scrollPercentage = (($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height()) / $(document).height()) * 100;

      if(scrollPercentage > 75 && !scope.in_progress && !scope.is_reached_end)
      {
        console.log('test')
        scope.$apply(attr.whenScrolled);
      }
    });
};
```

});

```
App.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider){
  $routeProvider.when('/', {
    templateUrl: 'views/offers.html',
    controller: 'OffersCntl'
  });
}]);
```

The view:

```
<div class="tileContainer" ng-controller="OffersCntl">
    <h2>Something very important :)</h2>
    <div id="tiles" class="tiles" when-scrolled="loadMore()">
        <div ng-view></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have a rather fat controller, which I don't want to polute the post with. It basically have a scope.loadMore method.

Comment: pls post the code to debug

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `ng-include` instead of `ng-view`.

http://jsfiddle.net/pvtpenguin/U7Bz9/540/

For example, in your view:

```
 <div class="tileContainer" ng-controller="OffersCntl">
   <h2>Something very important :)</h2>
   <div id="tiles" class="tiles" when-scrolled="loadMore()">
     <div ng-include src="'offer.html'"></div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: This is not a real solution, since ng-include does not provide the same functionality as ng-view does.

Answer (score 0):

This directive uses the scroll offset to give elasticity to the component and not limit it at a fixed height:

```
app.directive('whenScrolled', function($window, $timeout) {
  return {
    restrict: "A",
    link: function(scope, element, attr) {

      // bind the digest cycle to be triggered by the scroll event
      // when it exceeds a threshold
      angular.element($window).bind('scroll', function() {

        var supportPageOffset = window.pageXOffset !== undefined;
        var isCSS1Compat = ((document.compatMode || "") === "CSS1Compat");

        var scrollY = supportPageOffset ? window.pageYOffset : isCSS1Compat ? document.documentElement.scrollTop : document.body.scrollTop;

        var iScroll = element.prop('offsetTop') + element.prop('offsetHeight');
        var iScrooling =  scrollY + ( this.screen.height * 0.9 );

        //console.log(iScrooling+'/'+iScroll);

        if ( iScrooling >= iScroll ) {
          angular.element($window)[0].requestAnimationFrame(function(){
            // invoke the function passed into the 'whenScrolled' attribute
            scope.$apply(attr.whenScrolled);

          })
        }

      });
    }
  }
});
```

Your HTML:

```
<div class="tileContainer" ng-controller="OffersCntl">
   <h2>Something very important :)</h2>
   <div id="tiles" class="tiles" when-scrolled="loadMore()">
     <div ng-repeat="item in items">
       {{ item.id }}
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

The Controller, you can replace this with a request Ajax

```
$scope.items = [];

var counter = 0;
$scope.loadMore = function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        $scope.items.push({id: counter});
        counter += 10;
    }
};

$scope.loadMore();
```

> If you need support to old browsers, you can add this function:

```
//requestAnimationFrame for old browsers

(function() {
  var lastTime = 0;
  var vendors = ['webkit', 'moz'];
  for(var x = 0; x < vendors.length && !window.requestAnimationFrame; ++x) {
    window.requestAnimationFrame =     window[vendors[x]+'RequestAnimationFrame'];
    window.cancelAnimationFrame = window[vendors[x]+'CancelAnimationFrame'] || window[vendors[x]+'CancelRequestAnimationFrame'];
  }

  if (!window.requestAnimationFrame)
    window.requestAnimationFrame = function(callback, element) {
      var currTime = new Date().getTime();
      var timeToCall = Math.max(0, 16 - (currTime - lastTime));
      var id = window.setTimeout(function() { callback(currTime + timeToCall); }, timeToCall);
      lastTime = currTime + timeToCall;
      return id;
    };

  if (!window.cancelAnimationFrame)
    window.cancelAnimationFrame = function(id) {
      clearTimeout(id);
    };
}());
```