# ng-view and scroll event

Tags: javascript, angularjs, infinite-scroll, ng-view

I'm creating a SPA, with ng-router, and i need to use infinite scroll on one site inside ng-view, but I get a bit confused when ngInfiniteScroll hadn't fired. So i tried to do it on myself without any luck.

For simplicity :

**index.html**

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
...
<div ng-view id="whyDoYouWontScroll"> </div>
```

**pageToLoad.html**

```
<section ng-controller="someLazyCtrl" ng-init="initLazyLoad()"> 
    <div class="classWithSomeTremendousHeight"></div>
<section>
```

**someLazyCtrl.js**

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('someLazyCtrl',function($scope){
    $scope.initLazyLoad = function(){
        document.getElementById('whyDoYouWontScroll').addEventListener('scroll',function(){
            console.log('It's working!');
        });
    }
}
```

Event listener is added correctly, ng-view section have enough height to be scrolled, but... event is not firing.

I was looking around here, and found [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16449919/endless-scroll-doesnt-work-in-angularjs-when-scrolling-over-a-ng-view) but using ng-include is not a solution for me.

Comment: If the listener is added correctly, what doesn't work? Also what CSS are applied to the elements?

Comment: I'm using Material Angular, div have height for few screens, but event still not fires, and ng-view is block.

Comment: User angular.element instead

Comment: Fals listener is added correctly.

Answer (score 0):

gillsec thank you for your answer. You were right. Problem was with some flexbox, which shows the container were scrolled to bottom whole time.